# Finding the derivative of $v(r) = k(R^2 − r^2)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The velocity (in centimeters per second) of blood r cm from the central axis of an artery is given by

$$v(r) = k(R^2 − r^2)$$

where $k$ is a constant and $R$ is the radius of the artery. Suppose $k = 1000$ and $R = 0.3$ cm.

Find $v'(0.2)$.

I must be getting the wrong derivative. What Ive got is:

$$v'(r) = 2000R-2000r$$

I hope someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So we have $v(r) = k(R^{2} - r^{2})$.  Just by looking at the name of the function, $v(r)$, it is clear that this is a function with respect to the variable $r$.  That means $R$ and $k$ are just constants, and we treat them as constants when we find the derivative.

Since $v(r)$ is a function of only one variable, when we write $v'(r)$, we mean $\frac{dv}{dr}$, i.e., the derivative of $v(r)$ with respect to the variable $r$.

First, we write $v(r) = kR^{2} - kr^{2}$.  Now, $k$ and $R$ are just constants when we differentiate with respect to the variable $r$, so just like in the derivative of $x^{2} + 2000$, the constant $2000$ disappears and we are left with $2x$, here the $kR^{2}$ disappears because it is a constant.

So, $v'(r) = -2kr$.  This is exactly like differentiation $5000 - 6x^{2}$.  The derivative is $-(2)(6)x$. The $-k$ in the term $-kr^{2}$ acts like the $-6$ in $-6x^{2}$.

Anyway, so $v'(r) = -2kr$.  And since $k = 1000$, $v'(0.2) = -2(1000)(0.2) = -400$.

Answer (score 0):

It must be emphasized that $R$ and $k$ are **constants** so they can't be treated the same way $r$ is treated during differentiation. So $$v(r)=k(R^2-r^2) = kR^2-kr^2 \Rightarrow v'(r)=-2kr = -2000r$$

Answer (score 0):

$v(r)=k(R^{2}-r^{2})=kR^{2}-kr^{2}\Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d} v(r)}{\mathrm{d} r}=-2kr$

Notice that $R$ is considered constant in this differentiation just like $k$ is.

Answer (score 0):

$R$ is a constant. You are derriving with respect to $r$ only, thus the derivative is $$v'(r)=(kR^2)' -(kr^2)'=-(kr^2)'=-2kr$$